# Show the existance of a limit cycle for the Lotka-Volterra eqations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, limit-cycles

The question is as follows.
Consider the Lotka-Volterra equations:

$\dot{x}=\alpha x-\beta xy$

$\dot{y}=-\gamma y+\delta xy$

Use $V(x,y)=\delta x-\gamma ln(x)+\beta y-\alpha ln(y)$ to show that the populations undergo a limit-cycle if $x(0),y(0)>0$ is not an equilibrium.

It is my understanding that in order to prove a limit cycle exists I need to show that $\dot{V}\leq0$ for some set $M_1$ and $\dot{V}\geq0$ for some set $M_2$ and then I should get an Invariant set $M=M_{1}\cap M_{2}$ for which there is a limit cycle(Poincare - Bendixson). Only problem is that for the given $V(x,y)$, $\dot{V}=0$. So I'm not sure what my approach should be.

Comment: So $V$ is a first integral, and hence there is no limit cycle in this system. The system sits on the level sets of V, which can be shown to be closed curves (this is not an easy exercise if you'd like to have a proof for the whole positive cone).

Comment: @Artem So if there is no limit cycle in the system why am I tasked to show that there is? Trick question..? anyway, Thanks for the response

Comment: All orbits are closed all solutions periodic, but there is no locally attractive or repulsing limit. Some people might say that this is a borderline case of the "limit cycle" property, many other people do not.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I guess my professor is the former then. Thanks :)